# Access iframe from table td class without having Iframe ID

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

[image]

I am trying to access iframe which is inside in table. 
Can someone please suggest how to access that using jquery?

```
<table class="cke_editor">
   <tr>
      <td id="cke_contents_short_description">
          <iframe>
               <html>
                  <body id="cke_pastebin" style="color:red">
                  </body>
              </html>
          </iframe>
       </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

My problem is I want to remove `cke_pastebin` style from jquery which is inside in `table > iframe > td`.

Actually, I have done it for the simple body tag. Like as follows and it is working fine.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var isId = (document.body.id === 'cke_pastebin');
    if (isId) {
        $("#cke_pastebin").removeAttr("style");
    }
});
```

Can someone suggest how should I do this?

Comment: [`.children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/) might help you.

Comment: Hi Henders, Thanks for reply, but no its not . I have tried but didn't work

Comment: you have single iframe in whole html page or more than one ?

Comment: many iframes but its td id is different, I can't change its class or id because it is ckeditors file

Answer (score 1):

You can get child element using `.children()` method see the details [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_children.asp).

I have added code snippet which removes style attribute please check.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#cke_contents_short_description").children().removeAttr('style');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="cke_editor">
  <tr>
    <td id="cke_contents_short_description">
      <iframe style="width:500px;">
        <html>

        <body id="cke_pastebin" style="color:red">
        </body>

        </html>
      </iframe>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Another Method**

Try below code might be it can help.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".cke_editor > tbody > tr > td > iframe > body").removeAttr('style');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: @Joe I have updated my answer with code snippet please check.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But I want to remove specific "cke_pastebin's" style from "cke_contents_short_description"

Comment: @Joe try the another method I have added in my answer. I am able to remove style attribute for `iframe` not sure for body. please check the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Updated Syntax:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var temp = $(document).find("#cke_contents_short_description iframe").contents();
  temp.find('html body').html("Hello There , I am done it").css("color","red");
});
```

Comment: Hello Soni,
Thanks for reply.
I tried this,
var element = $('table.cke_editor').find('iframe').child('body#cke_pastebin');
alert(element);

but it is not working

Comment: and what for above one ? have you tried another one answer ?

Comment: hey! Joe , I did it at my side and update my syntax you can try with it .

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can do it **only for iframes on the same domain**, otherwise it would be [cross site scripting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). To access document within your `iframe` tag:

```
var iframe =$("#cke_contents_short_description").children("iframe")[0];
var innerDoc = $(iframe).contents();
```

Then, you can [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) element with desired `id` attribute in `iframeDocument` and run your removing code on it.

Comment: Could you please be more specific?

Comment: ya sure, 
Actually I am using ckeditor in which cke_pastebin is a ID which has some properties like overflow, position, top n all. n that is under iframe html body which is inside table. I wanted to remove that all properties if the iframe body has id "cke_pastebin".

Comment: What I meant by *more specific* is telling me what is not working in my solution :). Could you please tell me what is your console logging?

Comment: Showing your actual code would help us helping you as well - what I mean is your **exact** `iframe` , with it's `src` attribute, as your case might have something to do with **first sentence of my answer**.

Comment: please have a look on my question. I have added screenshot there

Comment: And what is in your console when you run my code with `console.log(innerDoc)` ?